# In Node.js, how do I inspect the local variables of a function?

Tags: node.js, reflection, introspection

How to see the locals of a function?

eg here, I can see that it is going to return `a+b`, but if its coming from a lib somewhere, then I have no idea what those things are:

```
fn = function() {
  var a=123, b=456;
  return function() { return a + b; };
}();
```

For comparison, here is how I would do it in Ruby:

```
fn = lambda do
  a, b = 123, 456
  lambda { a + b }
end.call

fn.binding.local_variable_get(:a) # => 123
fn.binding.local_variable_get(:b) # => 456
```

I'm willing to switch to io.js if it can give me this kind of ability to reflect on the system.

---

**Edit:**

It looks like Javascript isn't capable of doing this :( I don't understand how y'all figure out how to use an interface you've never seen before!

> Lexical Environments and Environment Record values are purely specification mechanisms and need not correspond to any specific artefact of an ECMAScript implementation. It is impossible for an ECMAScript program to directly access or manipulate such values.

-- https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-lexical-environments

Although, it Looks like there is [an interface to talk to the debugger](https://code.google.com/p/v8-wiki/wiki/DebuggerProtocol). Might be able to use that to elicit information?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the function and look at the local variables as of the breakpoint in the debugger.

Comment: How do I add the breakpoint to the function? All the examples I looked at make it appear that I need to be able to edit the source code. But say the source comes from a library, I can (and already have) edited from inside `node_modules`, but I need to be able to find the location of the function, at the very least. Again, in Ruby I would do `fn.source_location` and it would tell me the file and line number. But I don't know how to get that kind of feedback in JavaScript. Also, it feels like the interpreter should know, so I should be able to ask.

Comment: You run a debugger and you find the relevant source file and function and you set a breakpoint in it.  Or, if you know what calls it, you can set a breakpoint there and step into the function in question.

Comment: How do I find the relevant source? I determined that I can *see* the source with `console.log(fn.toString())`, but I have no idea how to determine where it comes from. I almost wrote a second question to ask this.

Comment: You would think the `toString()` method would know, but when I do `console.log(fn.toString.toString())`, it just prints `function toString() { [native code] }` I also looked at the `Reflect` class, but it didn't seem to have anything useful. At least, based on what was suggested on tab completion. I don't actually know how to identify that these are what it actually has available (in Ruby, I'd do `Reflect.methods`)

Comment: Also, what is the debugger doing? I can't seem to get anything on it, because it's a macro of some sort. But if I could see how it gets at that information, then I could just make my some helper functions that can answer questions like which locals it has, without me having to go grepping through the halls of my computer and littering globally installed node.js source code.

Comment: I use [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) for debugging my node.js server.  I get that your frustrated, but expressing that here isn't going to help you get answers.  It's an open source world.  You Google search for how to debug node.js applications and find several options and learn from there.  That's how I  learned.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at node-inspector, the video was really cool, but I don't have a web app, I just want to make a normal old js lib. Going to look into [the debugger api](https://code.google.com/p/v8-wiki/wiki/DebuggerProtocol), surely there is some way to query the system! Sometimes I'm jealous of of the things JS has (eg Babeljs and sweet.js make me drool!), but times like this, it just seems impoverished.

Comment: When you say "query the system", what you are trying to query for?  Local variables in a function don't exist unless you're in the middle of executing that function (e.g. at a breakpoint in that function or some function called from that function) or unless its a lasting closure for some reason and, in that case, you have to have the right context (which comes from a breakpoint) to even know which closure it is.

Comment: Well they definitely exist or they would be undefined when you call the function. Yeah, things like the value of a local, the location of a function, the context in which it was defined, the parameters of a function, the ability to look at some code I'm about to use and see what it's expecting. I'm not going to write my code to this (not into metaprogramming), but it's the only decent way I've found to figure out how a new library works, or how the language works. Esp in Node, where I have to go through like 20 packages to get to the bottom of a question, it seems hostile to inquiry.

Comment: Personally, I first use grep on the source code and look at how the code works in my editor.  I see what the functions expect.  I see what the code does with the arguments.  That's a beauty of an interpreted language where all source code is available.  If I need more info, I code a test program that calls the function and step through it in the debugger line by line and watch the values of variables and the flow through the function.  FYI, in an interpreted language local variables are created by the interpreter from the parsed representation of the function when the function is invoked.

Comment: BTW, what do you expect some tool to tell you about the variables of a function that isn't currently executing that you can't see by just looking at the source code yourself?

Comment: I can see the variable name, but I can't see the value. In the example I provided, I expect it to tell me that `a` is `123`.

Comment: A variable does not have a value until the code containing it is actually executing.  `var a = 123` is actually `var a;` and `a = 123;`.  So, until the statement `a = 123;` executes, there is no value in `a`.  If you want a runtime value, you have to insert code in the function to log the value when the function runs or set a breakpoint in a debugger in that function and inspect the value of the variable at a particular point in time of execution.  Until the function begins execution, `a` has no value and, in fact, a particular instance of `a` does not even exist yet.

Comment: I think you're chasing something that does not exist.  Runtime values only exist during the actual execution.  You can't sit outside of a program that isn't even running and inspect a local variable in some function.  At the point in time, the variable exists only in some parsed state internal to the JS engine as a statement that will declare a variable of that name when the function is actually executed and it has no value until code assigning it a value actually runs when the function is executed.  Before the function executes, the variable instance does not exist and has no value.

Comment: Please read the example again, `a` has a value, it is `123`, I already called the function that defined it, it is enclosed in return function's lexical scope. If I had put a print statement in there, it would have already printed by the time I want to see the value of `a`.

Comment: I didn't know you had already executed the function.  Now, you want to see inside a closure.  That is a private variable.  There will be no Javascript accessible way to get to that variable other than from a function you place within the closure (and make a method of `fn` because it is private.  Don't know about debugging tools.